# Wordpress page can't continue due to this error

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just faced this problem recently, I don't what causes it. But I need help fixing it.

The error are :

```
http://www.udesign.my/aaf4/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_checkout Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=century+gothic+:300,400 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

The theme I'm using is , `Love Fashion - Responsive WordPress Theme`

I've tried accessing my FTP, checked the CSS all pointing towards the font awesome.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error is a general server error (look for http 500 status code). It's very unspecific so it you could look up in your server logs fore more information.

Second error occurs because the font url can't be reached - try it for you self and open the url of the font in your browser. You will get an error.

> Error (400): Missing font family
>
> The requested font families are not available.
>
> Requested: century gothic (style: normal, weight: 300),century gothic
>   (style: normal, weight: 400)